# repeater inside a radiobuttonlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

hi I need to design a code like this image in asp.net:

[image]

the lists come from a database and the elements come from database too .

but I need to make each box : (1 list - multi element) is a separated radiobox 
so I can click any where inside the box and check the radio in it

I think about make a asp:RadioButtonList for the main datasource (for the list)

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and inside each radio make a repeater for the elements in every list ... how to do it ?
how can I add repeater inside a radiobuttonlist ?

I tried this code

:

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio" runat="server" DataSourceID="radio" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id">
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden" value='<%#Eval("id") %>'>
                            </asp:HiddenField>
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater" DataSourceID="repeaterds">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("name") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="repeaterds" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc %>" SelectCommand="select * from level where (team_id = @id)">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hidden" Name="@id" PropertyName="Value" />
                            </SelectParameters>


                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="radiods" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc %>" SelectCommand="select * from team"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but it's won't work because the radiobuttonlist didn't take sibling element

Comment: You don't need a repeater inside your radiobuttonlist. The elements in your radiobuttonlist will come from your data binding.

Comment: don't get it ??? 
but to be sure 
sqldatasource1 ... is to get the "list" from database 
sqldatasource2 ... is to get the "element" for each list from database

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: no idea except the radiolistbutton but it didn't let you to add a repeater inside it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i misunderstood your question, with no need for using repeater...

```
public class TData
{
    public String TText { get; set; }

    public UInt32 TValue { get; set; }
}

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TData> Data = new List<TData>
        {
            new TData{TText = "JSON", TValue = 0},
            new TData{TText = "C#", TValue = 1},
            new TData{TText = "JAVA", TValue = 2},
        };

        this.RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "TText";
        this.RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "TValue";
        this.RadioButtonList1.DataSource = Data;
        this.RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

all right, let's improve it

asp.net page

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" Text="<%# (Container.DataItem as Dummy.TData).TText %>" />
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# (Container.DataItem as Dummy.TData).TValue %>">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# (Container.DataItem as Dummy.TData1).TText %>"></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

and code behind:

```
public class TData1
{
    public String TText { get; set; }

    public String TValue { get; set; }
}

public class TData
{
    public String TText { get; set; }

    public List<TData1> TValue { get; set; }
}

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TData1> lst = new List<TData1> 
        {
            new TData1 {TText = "JSON", TValue = "0"},
            new TData1 {TText = "C#", TValue = "1"},
            new TData1 {TText = "JAVA", TValue = "1"}
        };

        List<TData> Data = new List<TData>
        {
            new TData{TText = "JSON", TValue = lst},
            new TData{TText = "C#", TValue = lst},
            new TData{TText = "JAVA", TValue = lst}
        };

        this.Repeater1.DataSource = Data;
        this.Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

it's done

[image]

Comment: mmm but there is a problem the word (json,c# , java) its not static its also came from sqldatasource

Comment: you misunderstand what I want ... I need like the li an ul 

like :
team 1 : 
   - samy - jack 
team 2 : 
   - alice - aska 

and the ability to select the team by press any where inside each ul

Comment: your can improve itemtemplate to fit your output style

Comment: it's gave me that error : 
The type or namespace name 'Dummy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)